# Code with border wrapping strangely inside paragraph

Tags: html, css

I was writing a CSS for a simple page and I've stumbled across a problem. I have a style for code that makes it have a simple border. The problem is when the line wraps inside that code when it's inside a paragraph. For example, the code below:

```
<!DOCYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <style type="text/css">
    p { text-align: justify; }
    code { border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 3px; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    Here I have a paragraph and a really long code text:
    <code>I'm a really long code text with a border.</code>
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: It appears something like this.]

When the line wraps inside the code element, the border stops in the first line and continues on the second incomplete at the break, which is kinda ugly. I'd like to make it so that the line can't wrap inside the code element as if this element is treated as a single word in a paragraph and appears entirely on the next line; or that the border stops when the line wraps and appears again when the next line starts. However, I have no idea of how to do this and I haven't found anything similar on the internet, can someone please help me?

Comment: there is nothing strange, that's how borders are drawn on inline elements ;) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display: inline-block` or `display: block` on the `code` element

```css
code {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Here I have a paragraph and a really long code text:
  <code>I'm a really long code text with a border. I'm a really long code text with a border.</code>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `outline` instead `border` :

```css
p {
  text-align: justify;
}

code {
  outline: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Here I have a paragraph and a really long code text:
  <code>I'm a really long code text with an outline border.</code>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix for tag `code`

More info - https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp

```css
code {display: inline-block)
```